how to set results path for playwright allure reports
How to set results path for playwright allure reports in C#.
I tried below paths and none of them work
public async Task OneTimeSetup() {
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ALLURE_RESULTS_DIRECTORY", @"C:\allure-results");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("allure-results", @"C:\allure-results");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ALLURE-RESULTS", @"C:\allure-results");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ALLURE_RESULTS_DIRECTORY", @"C:\allure-results");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ALLURE_RESULTS_DIR", @"C:\allure-results");

    // Clean up old results
    AllureLifecycle.Instance.CleanupResultDirectory();

    _playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
    _browser = await _playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions { Headless = false, SlowMo = 1000 });
}

I was expecting the results would be stored to c:\allure-results
